# How to update external_id for partners/companies and Where is default external_id is generating in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, openerp-8

I want to update all the external ids of res.partner in system while creating partners using create() method. Also, I am not getting the functionality where the default external id name(res_partner_id) is generating.

**Example :**

**Default generated external_id : res_partner_[id]**

**External id to be updated : abcd_res_partner_country_id_[id]**

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `External ID` is an identifier for a data record. The mechanism behind this is quite simple: Odoo keeps a table with the mapping between the named `External IDs` and their corresponding numeric database IDs. That is the `ir.model.data` model.

To inspect the existing mappings, go to the Technical section of the Settings menu, and select the Sequences & Identifiers | External Identifiers menu item.

Recommended link: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-update-external-id-50395